# How to determine the general polar equation of a circle

Tags: geometry

How can you determine that the polar equation $r = a\cos(\theta)$ is a circle?

Answer (score 5):

$r^2=ar\cos\theta$. Now use the substitutions $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $x=r\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
\begin{align}
y^2+(x-a/2)^2
&=\color{#C00000}{(r\sin(\theta))^2}+\color{#00A000}{(r\cos(\theta)-a/2)^2}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{a^2\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}+\color{#00A000}{a^2\cos^4(\theta)-a^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2/4}\\
&=\color{#0000FF}{a^2\cos^2(\theta)(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))}-a^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2/4\\
&=\color{#0000FF}{a^2\cos^2(\theta)}-a^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2/4\\
&=a^2/4
\end{align}
$$